# Multiple A1 and A9, then B1 and B9, then add the products together

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet and I'm basically trying to 'score' certain items.

I need to be able to take A1 (the individual score), then multiply it by A9 (the number of times i expect it to appear). Then B1 and B9, C1 and C9, etc. Then I need to add the products of {A1,A9},{B1,B9},{C1,C9}.

If you could put a function into a function (which hasnt seemed to work for me), it would look like this:

```
=AVERAGE(=PRODUCT({A1,A9}),=PRODUCT({B1,B9}),=PRODUCT({C1,C9}))
```

I looked at SUMPRODUCT then dividing by the number of products, but that seems to multiple A1 by B1 by C1 and then A9 by B9 by C9, then add that up, and then the division didnt work.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close if you are after the Average:

```
=AVERAGE(PRODUCT(A1,A9), PRODUCT(B1,B9), PRODUCT(C1,C9))
```

The curly brackets has the formula treat the value as an array, which you do not need in your case.  And you just put the various functions in without adding the extra = characters after that.

If you are after the sum, another minor change:

```
=SUM(PRODUCT(A1,A9), PRODUCT(B1,B9), PRODUCT(C1,C9))
```

Comment: Yup that was it. Thank you!